# document management systems for .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a new requirement to build a document management section to our existing asp.net mvc 3 application. We wish append multiple files to products. The files will be very large 1gb and will be various file types.

My question: 
are there any good .net libraries that offer some of the following

- good categorisation of files
- preferably asp.net mvc
- plugable into some kind of data storage like
- can manage large file
- some kind of ftp file upload option.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the same thing.  Some options:

1. SharePoint Foundation 2010 (free version)
2. [Kooboo](http://www.kooboo.com/)
3. [Atomic CMS](http://atomiccms.com/)
4. [Orchard CMS](http://orchardproject.net/)

The bottom three are all MVC based and open sourced.